# My For Loop Initial Conditions Reset Every Iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to run this for loop (Working in Matlab) and each time the loop is run, instead of the next iteration taking in the new velocity and position values, it just resets to the initial conditions that were given prior to the for loop. How can I fix this? At every iteration, I want the loop to take on a newly calculated position and velocity value take from the last row of the "S" matrix that the ODE solver outputs.

```
    %Initial position and velocity
    spart = [0.05 0.05 0.];
    vpart = [-1.7585E+7 -1.7585E+7 0.];

    %The entire time span MUST contain an even amount of indices for program to work!
    tstep = 0.1E-8; %Defining time step
    tfin = 0.7E-8; %Defining final time
    intspan = [0:tstep:tfin]; %Total time span
    [introw,intcol] = size(intspan);
    Wfor = zeros((3*(intcol)/2),6); %Generates matrix of zeros that the trajectory solver will populate later
    index = [0:1:intcol/2-1];

    for t = 0:1:intcol-2

%Assigns the numerical values of position and velocity to the following variables
        x = spart(1);
        y = spart(2);
        z = spart(3);
        vx = vpart(1);
        vy = vpart(2);
        vz = vpart(3);

        icv = [x; y; z; vx; vy; vz];
        %Time span
        tspan = [intspan(t+1) ((intspan(t+2)-intspan(t+1))/2)+intspan(t+1) intspan(t+2)];

        [T,S] = ode15s(@bdipuniodefun, tspan, icv);
        [rownum,colnum] = size(S);
        Wfor((1+2*t):(3+2*t),(1:6)) = S;

%Assigns the new velocity and position from the final row of the S matrix
        vparts(1) = S(rownum,4);
        vparts(2) = S(rownum,5);
        vparts(3) = S(rownum,6);
        sparts(1) = S(rownum,1);
        sparts(2) = S(rownum,2);
        sparts(3) = S(rownum,3);

    end
```

Comment: Also for context, the ODE solver is the "ode15s" function.

Comment: I think because at the beginning of the for loop you initialize your variables from `spart` while at the end of the loop you update `sparts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shamalaia is right. You should use the same variable name that initially assigned: spart & vpart.
Next time if you could, it would be nice to also include also your function @bdipuniodefun, in order to be able to test your code. Thanks!

**Proposed code:**

```
    for t = 0:1:intcol-2

%Assigns the numerical values of position and velocity to the following variables
        x = spart(1);
        y = spart(2);
        z = spart(3);
        vx = vpart(1);
        vy = vpart(2);
        vz = vpart(3);

        icv = [x; y; z; vx; vy; vz];
        %Time span
        tspan = [intspan(t+1) ((intspan(t+2)-intspan(t+1))/2)+intspan(t+1) intspan(t+2)];

        [T,S] = ode15s(@(t,y) t-y, tspan, icv);
        [rownum,colnum] = size(S);
        Wfor((1+2*t):(3+2*t),(1:6)) = S;

%Assigns the new velocity and position from the final row of the S matrix
        vpart(1) = S(rownum,4);
        vpart(2) = S(rownum,5);
        vpart(3) = S(rownum,6);
        spart(1) = S(rownum,1);
        spart(2) = S(rownum,2);
        spart(3) = S(rownum,3);

end
```

Comment: @Tom, if you are happy with the answer, can you accept it? or at least give me +1 to say that it was useful. Also give a +1 to shamalaia above as he was giving the right direction. Cheers!